# How to fetch the image from Firebase and save it to the Image in tableViewCell?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using a TableViewController and fetching image from firebase inside a Closure. I do get the name of the images in a local Database and saving it in an array at the time of fetching. But when I access the image array using **indexPath.row** everything gets collapsed(Instead of 2 images I need, all the images are getting replaced and it keeps on getting increased when I scroll the tableView). Please do guide me how to fetch the image inside the cell. Thanks in advance

```
var imageList = [UIImage]()
func getData()
    {
        Data = NSMutableArray()
        Data = ModelManager.getInstance().getAllData(planID)
        let count = Data.count
        for i in 0...count-1{
            let demoPlan = (Data.object(at: i) as! workoutPlan)
            ImageDemo.append(demoPlan.Image)

        }
    }


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell2:workoutplanCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "workoutplanCell") as! workoutplanCell
            cell2.planExerciseNameLabel.text = plan.Name

            if(plan.Image.contains("plank")){
                cell2.timerButton.isHidden = false
            }
            else{
                cell2.timerButton.isHidden = true
            }

            var new_imgList = [String]()
            new_imgList.append(ImageDemo[indexPath.row])
            new_imgList.append(ImageDemo[indexPath.row] + "1")

let storage = Storage.storage().reference()

            for x in new_imgList
            {
             let storageRef = storage.child("images/\(new_imgList[x]).jpg")
                storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                    if let error = error{
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    else{
                        self.imageList.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)

                    }
                    if  x == new_imgList{
                        cell2.planExerciseImage.animationImages = self.imageList
                        cell2.planExerciseImage.animationDuration = 2
                        cell2.planExerciseImage.startAnimating()

                        cell2.planDescription.delegate = self
                        cell2.planDescription.text = plan.Description
                        cell2.planDescription.sizeToFit()
                        cell2.planDescription.textColor = UIColor.black
                        self.imageList.removeAll()
                        new_imgList.removeAll()
                    }
                }

            }
           return cell2
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have that problem for two reasons:
One is the `imageList` scope. You have defined it somewhere in your `ViewController` and everytime a cell is set it keeps adding images.

And the second reason that is somewhat connected to the first one, is the `if  x == 1` i cant see that statement being called all the time, consequently your `imageList` will not be cleared for every cell.

Remove your `new_imgList` from wherever you have declared it and instead declare it  here:

```
for x in new_imgList{

  // DECLARE new_imgList HERE

.....

}
```

and delete the `self.imageList.removeAll()` line.

Comment: Hello there, thanks for helping I edited the code can you find the issue now

Comment: I have advised you what to do, is there a part that is not clear?

Comment: Yes bro the problem was with the scope of variable and it got resolved now thanks.